# Preserve Azure configuration settings on publish?

Tags: azure

When I use Windows Azure configuration settings, each time I publish an update to my cloud service, the settings are overwritten with the default from my project. This seems rather pointless to me, since if I want to override the default settings in the cloud, it makes sense that I want to preserve those overrides even when publishing an update to the app's code. Is there a way to preserve the settings when publishing from Visual Studio?

Comment: I agree, this seems to make the settings a bit pointless; or at least very annoying and risky to use, since it requires someone to remember to manually set all the settings that might be needed.

Comment: Specially when I can do that with web apps. Web.config doesn't get overwritten every time I push a new change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO - A redeploy of your service will override all the settings to whatever is set in the config file (.cscfg) that you provide. To preserve the settings you have to update both, the configuration file in the cloud and the configuration file on your local disk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - create a local ServiceConfiguration.cscfg (the default) and a cloud or prod configuration ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg.  Right click The cloud project and then "Manage Configurations" to add a new cscfg file.  In your publish settings, then specify "Cloud" as your service configuration.

But, if you are asking if you are asking if you can update the Azure Role without uploading settings, then NO - you have to upload a Service configuration file.

Comment: The azure websites's app configuration and connection string configuration in the portal will not be overrided by the publish, that  is a nice feature which the azure cloud service can do the same thing.

Comment: @iuhongbo - can you elaborate a little more? It sounds like what I want to do